# ADO REST API - Creating a Picklist - Where is it in the UI?

Tags: rest, azure-devops, field, azure-devops-rest-api, picklist

I need some assistance on creating a picklist. I am able to create a field and I am able to create a list(picklist) with the API. When I look in the web for field I see the field but when I look for the picklist I don't see it in the fields list for all processes. How do I create a picklist to have it in the list of fields for all processes in the UI?

Answer (score 0):

The essence of Picklist is the work item field. You can list the work item field one by one as instead:

You could return a field in a work item type using [Fields - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/fields/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/{processId}/workItemTypes/{witRefName}/fields/{fieldRefName}?api-version=6.0-preview.2
```

To return a list of all fields in a work item type, you can use [Fields - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/fields/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/{processId}/workItemTypes/{witRefName}/fields?api-version=6.0-preview.2
```